# Double page load how to prevent it?

Tags: php, load

I have the following if statement in PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['approved']))
    {
    // do stuff
    }
else
    {
    // give the user an error message
    }
```

Now the problem is that AND the if is getting executed AND the else is getting executed.

Now i've tracked the problem to a double page load problem and and a post and get request are sent at the same time or something like that but executed in the same file.

Simply put, how do I prevent this so my users don't get shipped with error messages whilst everything was done allright?

Is there a way to configure PHP to only allow a one time execution?

Trying to think about this gives me serious headaches, as if I have a parralel universe where the opposite happens but it all comes back to this universe as both have happened...

Schrodingers cat but without the collapsed wave function.

Comment: Yeeeeaaaaah, that's not happening. The error message is coming from somewhere else. There's no way you're executing what's in the `if` and `else` control structures in the same page load. Talk about a __MAJOR/CRITICAL__ PHP bug.

Comment: A vanilla browser isn't going to do this; you have to either have a script in the client or a `Header('Location: ...')` call on your page that's forcing it to double-execute.

Comment: Well, still that is what happens because if I comment out the error message it stops giving the error, so both are being executed.

Comment: Are you rewriting urls? Perhaps the browser is requesting `favicon.ico` and it gets rewritten to your script.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets But you're not posting your entire code. It's simply not happening that you're executing both the if and else in the same page load. My guess is that you have mis-matched curly braces on the page. Post the entire page on pastebin or something and link to it.

Comment: @jeroen Even if this were happening, they wouldn't both occur in the same page load.

Comment: @Colin Morelli The OP is talking about a `double page load problem` so it seems the script gets requested twice.

Comment: @jeroen Right but if the script gets executed twice, the browser is going to see the result of _one_ page execution. You can't be executing the same script twice in one request from the browser, and have the browser render a combined output of both executions. Think about that for a second, there's no way that make sense. A `header` redirect could cause this, but then you'd never see the output before the redirect. My point is that the question, as phrased, makes no sense.

Comment: @Colin Morelli Hmmmm, right, must be something in the code that is not shown...

Comment: @ColinMorelli You were right in this case. I had somewhere a lost `}` with 10 tabs in front of it behind a ; and not on the newline where it should have been and it dissapeared from view so I didn't see it... 
Still though I do encounter the double page load error sometimes, I do have it on another page where I rewrote the if statement so It wouldn't take in effect the $_POST variable because both got executed.
The problem could lie in the fact that I have multiple analysers running in my chrome browser. I've read that they could cause this  problem. @ColinMorelli could you post in an answer?

Answer (score 2):

If the page is being loaded twice, then the problem is not with your php in this file, it's a problem with the file that calls it. Basically, it's loading twice because it's being requested twice. Don't try to stop the php file from executing, stop the second request from happening.